# Show that $B=\{x\in A : (f_n(x)) \mbox{ converges} \}$ is measurable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f_n$ be bounded and (Lebesgue) measurable on bounded and (Lebesgue) measurable set $A$, for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Show that $B=\{x\in A : (f_n(x)) \mbox{ converges} \}$ is (Lebesgue) measurable.

---

The hint is to use Cauchy criterion of convergence, but I can't figure out how that would work.

Comment: do you know that $\limsup_n f_n(x)$ is a measurable function?

Comment: @clark yes, I do

Comment: So you know that $\liminf_nf_n(x)$ is measurable as well. Can you see a way to write the set of convergent points of $f$ in terms of these two measurable functions?

Comment: @clark The intersection of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$? Because a sequence of real numbers is convergent iff $\liminf$ is equal to $\limsup$?

Comment: By intersection do you mean $\{x|    \limsup _n f_n(x) =  \liminf _n f_n(x)  \}$?

Comment: @clark i meant sth else, but I see what is the correct idea now. We use the fact that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable then $\{x\in A: f(x)=g(x) \}$ is measurable too, right?

Comment: If you know that difference of two function is measurable i.e. $f-g$ is measurable and if you know that $  \{x|h(x)=c\}$ is measurable you can deduce that $\{x|f(x)=g(x)\}$ is measurable.

Comment: Thank you, I have already proved all those facts so I can use them

Answer (score 1):

$f_n(x)$ converges iff for every positive integer $M$ there is $N$ such that
for all $m,n > N$, $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < 1/M$.  Translate that into an intersection of a union of ...

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{M}$? And I don't know how to translate this into an intersection of a union of ...

Comment: Yes (edited). $\forall \mapsto \cap$, $\exists \mapsto \cup$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

Note that $\{x \in A : f_{n}(x) \text{ converges}\} = \{x \in A : -\infty < \liminf f_{n}(x) = \limsup f_{n}(x) < \infty \}$. 
Let $g_{0}^{*} := \liminf f_{n}$ and $g_{1}^{*} := \limsup f_{n}$. Further, let
$$g_{0}(x) := \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
g_{0}^{*}(x) & \text{if } -\infty < g_{0}^{*}(x) < \infty, \\\\
0 & \text{if } \ \big|g_{0}^{*}(x)\big| = \infty,
\end{array}\right. $$
and
$$g_{1}(x) := \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
g_{1}^{*}(x) & \text{if } -\infty < g_{1}^{*}(x) < \infty, \\\\
0 & \text{if } \ \big|g_{1}^{*}(x)\big| = \infty.
\end{array}\right.$$
It's easy to show that $g_{i}$ and $g_{i}^{*}$, $i = 1,2$ are measurable. Therefore $g := g_{0} - g_{1}$ is measurable. Thus,
$$\{ x \in A : f_{n}(x) \text{ converges}\} = g^{-1}[\{0\}] - \bigcup_{i=1}^{2}(g_{0}^{*})^{-1}[\{-\infty, \infty\}]$$
is measurable.